# gradle download artifacts every time upgrade gradle versions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Looks like everytime upgrade gradle to a new version I saw below logs in AndroidStudio:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 706 ms
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/7.4.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-7.4.2.pom, took 675 ms (1.33 kB)
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/library/com.android.library.gradle.plugin/7.4.2/com.android.library.gradle.plugin-7.4.2.pom, took 325 ms (1.32 kB)
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom, took 339 ms (11.14 kB)
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.module, took 117 ms (12.98 kB)
```

Does gradle download artifacts for each gradle version?
I would like to save my disk space!

Comment: Yes, Gradle downloads for each version an own program archive. Otherwise Gradle would be unmaintainable because of compatibility fixes for older versions. Or older scripts would not work anymore. So each Gradle script gets the version it was built for. If you are running out of disk space just delete the old versions.